# Need to replug my Magic Keyboard after each shutdown

Tags: keyboard, startup, bluetooth, login

Each time I restart my 2018 Mac mini running Mojave after a complete shutdown, I have to connect my Magic Keyboard (to USB) to be able to type my login/password.

Once it's done, I can unplug it and use it via Bluetooth.

Question; is it a "feature" for some security reason? Or is it a bug? (keyboard battery is at 100%).  How can I get it to retain the Bluetooth connection across reboots?

Comment: Hi, I have added the references. :)

Comment: I edited the question so it’s so its much easier to read.  Hopefully it’ll attract attention and answers!  +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit to Allan's edit because you have already said "2018 Mac mini running Mojave" so there is no reason to say it twice, or say "How can I get it to retain the Bluetooth connection across reboots?" twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my iMac running Catalina I can enter my password after reboot using the bluetooth Magic Keyboard without connecting it via cable. Although you run a different version of MacOS on a different machine it seems to me that this is rather a bug than a feature. Does it also appear after reboot or only after complete shutdown?

I have two ideas you can try to fix the problem: First, [reset your SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). If this doesn't solve the problem [reset your bluetooth controller](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/reset-mac-bluetooth-module/).

If both things don't work, connect the keyboard to another Mac to see if the problem is the same. If it is, I would order a new Magic Keyboard or go to an Apple store.

Comment: Hello, I've tested to reset the SMC, no result. For the Bluetooth reset, I don't have the "debug" option when hitting CTRML+OPTION + click on the Bluetooth icon. (mojave) i see new item like version, name, address.. but no debug submenu.

Comment: You have to press and hold Shift+Option while clicking the bluetooth icon.

Comment: You are right, I was doing control instead of shift. Seems to work after a reset of the bluetooth module. :)